# coreData: Moving record from NSSet entity

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, xcode6

I have CoreData model like this:
[image]
Were I already have data but I change the schedules and assign to movie.

Any of you knows how can accomplish this without duplicating the record?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your exact problem?  How have you tried to update the showTimes set?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an entity "Movie Screening" that will have relationship to one exact movie and to one exact theatre. Schedules should relate to these entities then